# How to take one part of a Series in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, series

How do I only take the values on the right? Ex. only have an array/list of [120, 108, 82...]

```
d = daily_counts.loc[daily_counts['workingday'] == "yes", 'casual']
d
```

[image]

Comment: `list(d)`? Also, you can chain your code with `to_list()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [`tolist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.tolist.html) or [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) or [`to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) method. Here is a toy example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,7,1,4]})
>>>    
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
5  7
6  1
7  4

>>> df['a'].value_counts() #generates similar output as you
>>> 
4    2
1    2
7    1
5    1
3    1
2    1
Name: a, dtype: int64

>>> df['a'].value_counts().tolist() #extracting as a list
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]

>>> df['a'].value_counts().values #extracting as a numpy array
array([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])

>>> df['a'].value_counts().to_numpy() #extracting as a numpy array
array([2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```